# The value passed in onclick() attribute of dynamically generated anchor tag is ending with first space

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

have to pass two parameters in the onlclick() of anchor tag which is being generated from code behind(c#).if there is any space in the first parameter the onclick() is being closed with double quotes. It is not taking the complete value.

```
         LiteralControl lc2 = new LiteralControl();
                lc2.Text = String.Format("<a href='#' class='easyui-linkbutton' " + @"onclick=addTab(" + childMenus[j].MenuName.ToString() + "," + url + @")> " + @" Setting " + @" </a>");
```

screenshot of browser's inspect element :
[image]

the value of first parameter is "Exam and course setting" but it is ending after "Exam" at first space. It is assuming space as ending.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with spaces, and everything to do with quotes. You have to escape the quotes in the string literal, otherwise you're ending the attribute

Comment: @adeneo thanks for answering. I cant escape all the quotes since there is concatenation of string. Here is what i have written with the minimum quotes  but still getting the same problem:      lc2.Text = String.Format("<a href=# class=easyui-linkbutton  onclick=addTab('" + childMenus[j].MenuName.ToString() + "'," + url + ")>  Setting  </a>");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the controls in my `lc2` string to use string variables to demonstrate how you can create the escaped html:

```
string MenuName = "Exam and course setting";
string url = "http://stackoverflow.com";

var lc2 = "<a href='#' class='easyui-linkbutton' " + @"onclick='addTab(""" + MenuName.ToString() + @""",""" + url + @""")'>" + @"Setting" + @"</a>";
```

which will generate the following:

```
<a href='#' class='easyui-linkbutton' onclick='addTab("Exam and course setting","http://stackoverflow.com")'>Setting</a>
```

Don't forget to HTMLEncode any text from the controls if they contain single or double quotes. You can replace with `&#39;` for `'` and 
`&#34;` for `"`.

Comment: Also you don't need to use `String.Format()` in your code, just assign the value to lc2.Text.